# Train darknet again on a bigger dataset

Tags: custom-object, darknet

I just finished training YOLOv3 on darknet on my custom dataset which only had 100 images. Now i want to train it for a bigger dataset(500 images). I was wondering if there was any way i could use this pre-trained model to train on my new dataset without starting from the beginning. 
Also, will it train quickly than before?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the pre-trained weights to continue training with the new set of images. Check this [How to train tiny-yolo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/#how-to-train-tiny-yolo-to-detect-your-custom-objects).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that, just *continue* your training with yout last saved model.
Something like

```
./darknet detector train data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg yolov4.conv.137
```

Change **yolov4.conv.137** for your last saved model

```
./darknet detector train data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg backup/yolov3_last.weights
```

You have to change your **max_batches** in your cfg, because your training will continue where it ended.

And maybe your model will converge to a better model faster than before, but as you are loading 5 times more images, it can be slower.